# Where are built-in method in javascript?

Tags: javascript

please help me get it straight, I see every object in javascript leads to object Object in prototype chain and then to null, in console.log we can see properties and methods of objects but never its implementation, i wonder if this Object is a top-level object where all built-in are stored, is that so?

thank you all for answers!

Comment: I would recommend ALWAYS reading the documentation of an object before using it. As far as seeing its methods in the log, I'm not sure, but you shouldn't have to if you read the documentation. The doc should have all its methods as well as what they do and their parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is an object-based language. Which means that "everything" inherits from an Object, except Object itself, **the top of the prototype chain is null**. When you declare an array, you can use `.lenght` because that is defined in the prototype attribute. There are some exceptions, such as int, floats, etc.

In fact, when you run a console, you can see every method from its parents. Try creating a Constructor for a new object, let's say, for example:

```
var Person = function(name, yearOfBirth, job) {
    this.name = name;
    this.yearOfBirth = yearOfBirth;
    this.job = job;
}
```

Add a method to this Person's prototype:

```
Person.prototype.calculateAge  = function() {
    console.log(2016 - this.yearOfBirth);
};
```

And create an instance of this new "class":

```
var sarah = new Person('Sarah', 1994, 'programmer');
```

Now go to the console on your browser and type `sarah` to see it's methods and variables. You'll notice that variables that are exclusive for John will appear on the first drop-down, but you'll also notice that John does not have `calculateAge` attached directly to it. That's because it's in its prototype, search for something called `_proto_` and you'll see this method and also a construct and guess what else? Another `_proto_`, this time, it's the proto from Person's parent, or, in other words, the Object.

There you can find most of the methods from the `Object` itself.

Prototypes are what makes inheritance possible in javascript

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want to look at ECMA specifications?

http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm

Each browser may have its own implementation of Javascript. Maybe something like this repo will help.

https://github.com/v8/v8